# PHPMailer SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed. Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I’ve tried to upgrade to PHPMailer 6 and have run into some problems. I installed composer first and then installed PHPMailer with command `require phpmailer/phpmailer`

Then I created a composer.json file in my Sites folder and used `composer install` in Terminal

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~6.0"
    }
}
```

Installation seemed to be successful, the vendor folder was created in Sites but then when I tried to use the example script from phpmailer I get the following error:

```
2017-11-28 12:03:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP o88sm45054643wrc.10 - gsmtp
2017-11-28 12:03:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2017-11-28 12:04:09 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2017-11-28 12:04:09 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed: 
2017-11-28 12:04:09 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

My php code is:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                    // Passing `true` enables exceptions
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                       // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';             // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'myusername@gmail.com';   // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'mypassword';             // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                          // TCP port to connect to

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('myusername@gmail.com', 'My Name');
        $mail->addAddress('myusername@gmail.com', 'My Name');       // Add a recipient
        $mail->addReplyTo('myusername@gmail.com', 'My Name');
        $mail->addCC('another-email');
        $mail->addBCC('another-email');

        //Attachments
        $mail->addAttachment('images/facebook.png');         // test attachment

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                        // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
        $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent. ';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }

}
```

I've looked through so many answer to similar errors and tried all the following:
Signing out and back in to Google using password so I know is correct.

I’ve followed security settings in Google
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps - allow less secure apps is ON
https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha - account access enabled

Also looked through troubleshooting
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Using `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` in Terminal is successful

While looking into this I noticed that while I have php7 installed and working I can’t find a php7 folder and still have php5 which seems to contain all the php files.

There are also two php.ini files - in phpinfo the path to php.ini is usr/local/php5/lib while Terminal command `php -- ini` says Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php.ini

I also get the following errors in the log when I restart Apache - not sure if it's connected but thought I'd post just in case

*[Apache errors removed when ServerName set to localhost]*

I’m not sure if the double php.ini files would affect anything in PHPMailer but I’ve now run out of things to try.

Please help! Wishing I hadn't upgraded as it was working before.

Comment: I tested your code on my machine where it goes past the EHLO stage. Try running the commands on telnet to see if they work.

Comment: Not sure how to run the commands in telnet
I typed `telnet localhost` in terminal and got the following:
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: Also tried `telnet 127.0.0.1 25` and 23 as suggested in other posts but still get connection refused.
`telnet localhost 80` connects successfully
`apachectl configtest` says Syntax OK

Comment: Try `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` and type in EHLO localhost to see if it works. According to the debug output of PHPMailer, that's where it fails.

Comment: That seems to work!
Trying 74.125.133.108...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP o63sm7750226wmb.4 - gsmtp

Comment: What happens if you type `EHLO localhost` after this ? If everything goes well, it should respond with `250-smtp.gmail.com at your service,`

Comment: I get Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: If I do `telnet.gmail.com 587` then type 'EHLO smtp.gmail.com' I get the following which looks good to me
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [147.197.251.158]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160018/discussion-between-user3606041-and-hassan).

Comment: You really want to avoid that `EHLO localhost` - your real host name should be in there mail servers like real host names, and they like it even more when forward and reverse DNS lookups match. If it's failing to set it automatically, you can set it explicitly in the PHPMailer `Hostname` property - note that this is **not** the same as the `Host` property (where you're connecting *to*).